# After uploading images the input field is showing "no file chosen"

Tags: vue.js

Here is my vue form generator schema. And here I have written a code form uploading the images. And the images are uploading fine but the big issye while i am uploading the images the name of the image at input field is not displaying. like if i am uploading the image the name if not showing but the image is uploading fine while we seeing at preview page. I am struggling to solve this issue alot please if anyone have an idea let me know

In the below image the image is uploaded but still showing "no file choose"
[image]

```
<vue-form-g :schema="Images" :model="model" :options="formOptions"></vue-form-g>
```

*vue form generator*

```
new Vue({
 el: '#q-vikreya',

    components: {
        "vue-form-g": VueFormGenerator.component
    },

<!--All categories we bind here and accessed in templates-->
    data() {
            return {
            image_1: '',
Images: {
            fields: [{
                type: "image",
                placeholder: "Upload file",
                required: true,
                files: true,
                model: "image_1",
                preview:true,
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-4", "image_1"],
                validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.text
            }, {
                type: "image",
                placeholder: "Upload file",
                required: true,
                files: true,
                model: "image_2",
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-4", "image_2"],
                validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.text
            },{
                type: "image",
                placeholder: "Upload file",
                required: true,
                files: true,
                model: "image_3",
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-4", "image_3"],
                validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.text
            },{
                type: "image",
                placeholder: "Upload file",
                required: true,
                files: true,
                model: "image_4",
                preview: true,
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-4", "image_4"],
                validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.text
            },{
                type: "image",
                placeholder: "Upload file",
                required: true,
                files: true,
                model: "image_5",
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-4", "image_5"],
                validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.text
            },{
                type: "image",
                placeholder: "Upload file",
                required: true,
                files: true,
                model: "image_6",
                preview: true,
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-4", "image_6"],
                validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.text
            }]
         },
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? What are you using to generate forms?

Comment: I have updated my code please review it. Here I am using vue form generator.

Comment: Maybe `:schema="Images.fields"` instead `:schema="Images"`

Comment: tested but not working with that